# UWP reference control outside of data template

Tags: xaml, winrt-xaml, windows-10

I'm trying to create a listview that has column headers and the lists fields mimics the width of its corresponding header. No bindings fail but the textblocks width in the data template don't match up with their headers width. I'm guessing because the data template can't find the element. Any ideas to get this to work?

```
                <Grid Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" x:Name="listViewHeaders" Height="50" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="10,0" >
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition />
                    <ColumnDefinition />
                    <ColumnDefinition />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <!--<controls:CustomGridSplitter/>-->
                <TextBlock x:Name="nameHeader" Grid.Column="0" Text="Name" />
                <TextBlock x:Name="typeHeader" Grid.Column="1" Text="Type" />
                <TextBlock x:Name="colorHeader" Grid.Column="2" Text="Color" />
            </Grid>
            <ListView x:Name="ListView" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Background="#FF494949" Margin="10,50,10,0" ItemsSource="{Binding CurrentCardList}">
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Grid Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=ListView}">
                            <!--<Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />

                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>-->
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=nameHeader}" Text="{Binding Name}" />
                                <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=typeHeader}" Text="{Binding Type}" />
                                <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=colorHeader}"  Text="{Binding Color}" />
                            </StackPanel>
                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
                    </Style>
                </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
            </ListView>
```

Answer (score 3):

The bindings work fine. But you're assuming that `TextBlock` elements in the header row will fill out the entire table cell, which they won't. They only fill as much space as much text they contain. In your case that's about 30px. You can find this information by using the *Live Visual Tree* feature of VS 2015.

You can solve the problem by wrapping the header `TextBlock` elements in another element that will fill out all available space, such as `Border`. Here's the solution:

```
    <Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <Grid x:Name="listViewHeaders" Height="50" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="10,0" >
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition />
            <ColumnDefinition />
            <ColumnDefinition />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <!--<controls:CustomGridSplitter/>-->
        <Border Background="Blue" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Grid.Column="0" x:Name="nameHeader">
            <TextBlock Text="Name" />
        </Border>
        <Border Background="Red" x:Name="typeHeader" Grid.Column="1">
            <TextBlock Text="Type" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" />
        </Border>
        <Border Background="Yellow" x:Name="colorHeader" Grid.Column="2">
            <TextBlock Text="Color" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" />
        </Border>
    </Grid>
    <ListView x:Name="ListView" Background="#FF494949" Margin="10,50,10,0" ItemsSource="{Binding CurrentCardList}">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=ListView}">
                    <!--<Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />

                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>-->
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=nameHeader}" Text="{Binding Name}" />
                        <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=typeHeader}" Text="{Binding Type}" />
                        <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=colorHeader}"  Text="{Binding Color}" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
            </Style>
        </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
    </ListView>
</Grid>
```

This will create the following effect, which I believe is what you're after.

[image: TextBlock widths corresponding to headers]

Here's the link to the complete solution - http://1drv.ms/1eUzLHl

Comment: actually the items are the problem. My headers are in the correct spot but the items are all bunched up. they all seem to be a set size and all bunched up, unlike yours. My code is exactly the same too. I can't get my visual studio to "Show properties" in my live visual tree either :/

Comment: @shady I've added a link to the complete solution, take a look.